# How to add button at bottom of dropdown in selectize js

Tags: selectize.js

How to add button in sibling of div.selectize-dropdown-content div.
So that list item should scroll as usual but that button should be fixed at bottom.

I have gone through plugin for selectize js but all the render function is only for list , header and item.

[image]

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $select = $('#select-state').selectize({
                sortField: 'text',
                hideSelected: false,
                plugins: {
                    'dropdown_header': {
                        title: '<button class="btn full-width ng-binding" data-options="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Yeni Ekle</button>'
                    }
                }
            });
```